# how to lock screen until pdf is generated in c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

hi I have this program that has a  with a link that, once clicked, starts the download of a file. i need to add a loading screen until the file is downloaded.

i've seen this [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532788/how-to-display-a-loading-animation-while-file-is-generated-for-download) solution but when implementing the

```cs
Response.Cookies.Add(
    new HttpCookie("downloadStarted", "1") 
    { 
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(20) 
    });
```

the program stops working (no more fader). also this solution has deprecated lines of code. please help thanks

the button

```html
<a href="@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CarrelloDownload", "Carrello", new {}))", class="btn btn-primary">Scarica</a>
```